# Hair dynamics loop

Tags: animation, particles, hair, loop, dynamic

Im trying to create an idle animation for a character with a **hair dynamics/particle** effect and I keep uncovering different ways a **loop** does not work. The model animation loops fine, but the hair resets & makes a terrible loop.
I have looked at particle loop videos & gathered that the loop uses 2 particle systems ending and starting on sequential fames, however none of them provide enough info about translating it to hair.
Hair is always settling in the first few frames. A section of the frames are perfect, that's all I would like to use. In the cache, I've tried baking the sim with 'start' and 'end' but it starts the sim at that fame, not the bake. **I thought about baking a frame range** & then running it forward then backward sequentially, but I cant seem to find an option to 1) bake specific frames & 2) import the bake, **3) run it backwards to make a loop**.
I have fought with this hair for a few days now & finally managed the hair to be chill and normal for 30 frames that I could bake. **I managed an un-synced loop by having the start/end frames not equaling my timeline frames.**
Its the only work around I have found in this time, **there has to be a better way to do this.** I cant imagine this much work for an idle animation.
There are lots of scenes in the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S1hAXpJ-8zDggFN_LdnQqiTGEmmRGD5G/view?usp=drive_link)  I am working between the "Kinidle" scene and the "KinTroub" scene. Feel free to grab any materials out of the texture scene. additionally ignore the cloth simulation issues I have going on.... that's a different post.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The idea of using dynamics for hair is precisely to let it do its thing at runtime and not caring about it fitting whatever the animation does. There shouldn't be a need to make it cyclic. What is your end goal here?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. The end goal was to make a loop idle animation. Should I use a different set up for hair then?

Comment: where is that animation used?